# How to replace one backspace or two backspaces in a row and character before them in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have code like this:

```
string.replace(/(.|\r\n)\x08/g, '');
```

that replaces backspace and one character before it,  but it will not work for cases where there are more then one backspace in a row, like `'foo\b\b'`. How can I remove characters that are before backspaces so I get string `'f'`.

Comment: If you replace one character before the backspace, then how do you come up with `f` out of `foo\b\b`? This means you want to replace as many characters as backspaces, doesn't it?

Comment: @cezar Yes, you're right.

Comment: What should be the expected result for `foo\bo\b\b`?

Comment: Ok, I believe my answer should meet your requirements then. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
str="abc\b\bdefg";
while(str.match(/\w\x08/)){
   str=str.replace(/\w\x08/g,"");
}
```

It will keep removing a "character + back space" sequence, while they are still in the string.

Comment: I ended up with regex like this `/([^\x08]|\r\n)\x08/` because I need to match every character and also `\r\n` need to be single character.

Answer (score 0):

'+' means  '1 or more', so try
    string.replace(/(.|\r\n)+\x08/g, '')

Comment: This will replace everything to the begining of the string.

Comment: Sorry, wrong place to plus, string.replace(/(.|\r\n)\x08+/g, '');

Comment: And this will replace `'foo\b\b'` by `'fo'` not `'f'`

Comment: I dont understand. You need replacement like abc\b\bdefg ->  \b\bdefg?

Comment: I need `abc\b\bdefg -> adefg`.

Comment: Try 'abc\b\bdefg'.replace(/.+\x08+/g, '')

Comment: Nope. Wait a moment... Thinking

Comment: As I said it will replace everything before backspace. if you run that on 'foo\b' you'll get empty string.

Comment: Sorrry, but looks like in JS not supported that stuff. You can use that
x='abc\b\bdefg'
function reprepl(a){
return a.replace(/.\x08/g, '')}
while(x!=(x=reprepl(x))){};
console.log(x)

Comment: If there is a not so mutch \b in string also will works :

string.replace(/(.\x08|..\x08\x08|...\x08\x08\x08)/g, '')

and so on/

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
'foo\b\b'.replace(/((?:[^\x08]|\r\n)+)(\x08+)/g, function(_, chars, backspaces) {
    return chars.replace(new RegExp('(.|\r\n){' + backspaces.length + '}$'), '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete one or two 0x08 characters in the string and the character before them just change the regex to

> /(.|\r\n)\x08{1,2}/g

But I think what you want to do is delete 1 character per 0x08 you can do this like this

> /((.|\r\n)\x08|(.|\r\n){2}\x08{2})/g

for two. If you want to do it for more I think it will just be faster to write a function that goes over the string char by char and parses it one iteration

```js
function removeBackslashes(str){
  var result = "";  
  for(var i in str){
    if(str.charCodeAt(i) == 8)
    {      
      result = result.slice(0, -1);
    }else{
      result += str.charAt(i);  
    }
  }  
  return result;
}

var b = removeBackslashes('foo\b\basd');
console.log(b, b.length);
```